# how to calculate accuracy based on two lists python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two lists.

```
  a = [0,0,1,1,1]   # actual labels
  b = [1,1,0,0,1]   # predicted labels
```

How can I calculate accuracy based on these lists?

Comment: How do you define accuracy? % correct?

Comment: If the numbers in both lists are all the same.  Say all ones.  Then Accuracy can be said to be 100 percent, however this can be misleading because a classifier that always predicts 1 is maximally useless and so you have to make a frequency table and return correctionally weighted sum of accuracies of all bins.  And return null if accuracy isolation is physically impossible for this small dataset

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
sum(1 for x,y in zip(a,b) if x == y) / len(a)
```

This will give you the percentage that were correct - that is, the number correct over the total number. It works by calculating the number that are equal between the two lists then dividing by the total number of labels.

Also note that if you're not using Python 3, it will have to look like this:

```
sum(1 for x,y in zip(a,b) if x == y) / float(len(a))
```

To ensure you get a decimal representation of the number

Answer (score 5):

Since you've tagged `numpy`, here's a `numpy` solution:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,0,1,1,1])   # actual labels
b = np.array([1,1,0,0,1])   # predicted labels

correct = (a == b)
accuracy = correct.sum() / correct.size
```

Answer (score 4):

If the two lists are always the same size, the following code should be okay :)

```
a = [0,0,1,1,1]   # actual labels
b = [1,1,0,0,1]   # predicted labels

accuracy = len([a[i] for i in range(0, len(a)) if a[i] == b[i]]) / len(a)
print(accuracy)
```

Answer (score 2):

if accuracy is defined as % correct:

```
count = 0.0
correct = 0.0
for i in range(len(a)):
  count+=1
  if a[i]==b[i]:
    correct+=1
print correct/count
print (correct/count)*100
```

This will print decimal representation of % correct, followed by % representation.