# Compute precision and accuracy using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose two lists `true_values = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]` and `predictions = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]`. How can I compute the accuracy and the precision using numpy?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to calculate accurady based on two lists python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877301/how-to-calculate-accurady-based-on-two-lists-python)

Answer (score 13):

```
import numpy as np

true_values = np.array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]])
predictions = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]])

N = true_values.shape[1]
accuracy = (true_values == predictions).sum() / N
TP = ((predictions == 1) & (true_values == 1)).sum()
FP = ((predictions == 1) & (true_values == 0)).sum()
precision = TP / (TP+FP)
```

This is the most concise way I came up with (assuming no sklearn), there might be even shorter though!

Comment: `precisions = (predictions * true_values).sum() / predictions.sum()`.

Comment: `np.mean(true_values == predictions)`

Answer (score 1):

This is what `sklearn`, which uses `numpy` behind the curtain, is for:

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, accuracy_score

accuracy_score(true_values, predictions), precision_score(true_values, predictions)
```

Output:

```
(0.3333333333333333, 0.375)
```

Comment: I can't use sklearn. Are you up to show me using numpy in the more concise way possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to calculate it yourself instead of using a library like in [Quang Hoang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64210637/261142), just count the number of (true|false) (positives|negatives) and plug the values into your formula:

```
tp = 0
tn = 0
fp = 0
fn = 0

for t,p in zip(true_values, predictions):
   if t == p:
       if p == 1:
           tp += 1
       else:
           tn += 1
   else:
       if p == 1:
           fn += 1
       else:
           fp += 1

accuracy = (tp + tn) / (tp + tn + fp + fn)
precision = tp / (tp + fp)
```

This [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) has a nice info box with formulas that use exactly these values.

Comment: While this is correct, almost no body compute these values this way :).

Comment: @Quang Hoang: Agreed :) I posted it mostly for educational purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only going to answer for precision, because I posted a duplicate for accuracy and there should be one question per thread:

```
sum(map(lambda x, y: x == y == 1, true_values, predictions))/sum(true_values)
```

```
0.5
```

Use `np.sum` if you absolutely want to use Numpy

Here is for the mean:

```
np.equal(true_values, predictions).mean()
```

Comment: Come on, post the accuracy code as well for the sake of completeness.

Comment: FYI, a reason to close questions on this site is "There is more than 1 question in the post".

Comment: I would like to see your answer for the accuracy. Please

Comment: @David For accuracy, remove the `== 1` part in the numerator and replace `sum` with `len` in the denominator.